# Only the first carousel work out of a multiple ones in the same page

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging

I tried to add the for loop to go through each carousel, but when I do that, now non of them works. Before I added the for-loop, only the first one worked.

initially it was :

```
querySelector('.carousel')
```

Then I changed it to :

```
querySelectorAll('.carousel')
```

```js
var carousel = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel'), i;

for (i = 0; i < carousel.length; ++i) {

firstImg = carousel[i].querySelectorAll("img")[0];
arrowIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper i");

let isDragStart = false, isDragging = false, prevPageX, prevScrollLeft, positionDiff;




carousel[i].addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
carousel[i].addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
carousel[i].addEventListener("touchmove", dragging);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
carousel[i].addEventListener("touchend", dragStop);
}


const showHideIcons = () => {
    // showing and hiding prev/next icon according to carousel scroll left value
    let scrollWidth = carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth; // getting max scrollable width
    arrowIcons[0].style.display = carousel.scrollLeft == 0 ? "none" : "block";
    arrowIcons[1].style.display = carousel.scrollLeft == scrollWidth ? "none" : "block";
}

arrowIcons.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14; // getting first img width & adding 14 margin value
        // if clicked icon is left, reduce width value from the carousel scroll left else add to it
        carousel.scrollLeft += icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
        setTimeout(() => showHideIcons(), 60); // calling showHideIcons after 60ms
    });
});

const autoSlide = () => {
    // if there is no image left to scroll then return from here
    if(carousel.scrollLeft - (carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth) > -1 || carousel.scrollLeft <= 0) return;

    positionDiff = Math.abs(positionDiff); // making positionDiff value to positive
    let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14;
    // getting difference value that needs to add or reduce from carousel left to take middle img center
    let valDifference = firstImgWidth - positionDiff;

    if(carousel.scrollLeft > prevScrollLeft) { // if user is scrolling to the right
        return carousel.scrollLeft += positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff;
    }
    // if user is scrolling to the left
    carousel.scrollLeft -= positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff;
}

const dragStart = (e) => {
    // updatating global variables value on mouse down event
    isDragStart = true;
    prevPageX = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX;
    prevScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
}

const dragging = (e) => {
    // scrolling images/carousel to left according to mouse pointer
    if(!isDragStart) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = true;
    carousel.classList.add("dragging");
    positionDiff = (e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX) - prevPageX;
    carousel.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - positionDiff;
    showHideIcons();
}

const dragStop = () => {
    isDragStart = false;
    carousel.classList.remove("dragging");

    if(!isDragging) return;
    isDragging = false;
    autoSlide();
}
```

```css
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
body{
  //display: flex;
  padding: 0 35px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #343F4F;
}
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper i{
  top: 50%;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  color: #343F4F;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}
.wrapper i:active{
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
.wrapper i:hover{
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.wrapper i:first-child{
  left: -22px;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper i:last-child{
  right: -22px;
}
.wrapper .carousel{
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.carousel.dragging{
  cursor: grab;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}
.carousel.dragging img{
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel img{
  height: 340px;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.carousel img:first-child{
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .carousel img{
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .carousel img{
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Draggable Image Slider | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div>
  
    <div class="wrapper">
      <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
      <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        
        
      </div>
      <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    <p>
    hihifdd
    </p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
      <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        <img src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg" alt="img" draggable="false">
        
      </div>
      <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to bring the rest of the functions into the `for` loop, and adjust the code so that the functions reference properties from the curent carousel element being iterated upon:

```js
var carousel = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel"),
  i;

for (i = 0; i < carousel.length; ++i) {
  const thisCourusel = carousel[i];
  const firstImg = thisCourusel.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
  const arrowIcons = thisCourusel.closest(".wrapper").querySelectorAll("i");

  let isDragStart = false,
    isDragging = false,
    prevPageX,
    prevScrollLeft,
    positionDiff;

  const dragStart = (e) => {
    // updatating global variables value on mouse down event
    isDragStart = true;
    prevPageX = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX;
    prevScrollLeft = thisCourusel.scrollLeft;
  };

  const dragging = (e) => {
    // scrolling images/carousel to left according to mouse pointer
    if (!isDragStart) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = true;
    thisCourusel.classList.add("dragging");
    positionDiff = (e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX) - prevPageX;
    thisCourusel.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - positionDiff;
    showHideIcons();
  };

  const dragStop = () => {
    isDragStart = false;
    thisCourusel.classList.remove("dragging");

    if (!isDragging) return;
    isDragging = false;
    autoSlide();
  };

  thisCourusel.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
  thisCourusel.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
  thisCourusel.addEventListener("touchmove", dragging);

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
  thisCourusel.addEventListener("touchend", dragStop);

  const showHideIcons = () => {
    // showing and hiding prev/next icon according to carousel scroll left value
    let scrollWidth = thisCourusel.scrollWidth - thisCourusel.clientWidth; // getting max scrollable width
    arrowIcons[0].style.display =
      thisCourusel.scrollLeft == 0 ? "none" : "block";
    arrowIcons[1].style.display =
      thisCourusel.scrollLeft == scrollWidth ? "none" : "block";
  };

  arrowIcons.forEach((icon) => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14; // getting first img width & adding 14 margin value
      // if clicked icon is left, reduce width value from the carousel scroll left else add to it
      thisCourusel.scrollLeft +=
        icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
      setTimeout(() => showHideIcons(), 60); // calling showHideIcons after 60ms
    });
  });

  const autoSlide = () => {
    // if there is no image left to scroll then return from here
    if (
      thisCourusel.scrollLeft -
        (thisCourusel.scrollWidth - thisCourusel.clientWidth) >
        -1 ||
      thisCourusel.scrollLeft <= 0
    )
      return;

    positionDiff = Math.abs(positionDiff); // making positionDiff value to positive
    let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14;
    // getting difference value that needs to add or reduce from carousel left to take middle img center
    let valDifference = firstImgWidth - positionDiff;

    if (carousel.scrollLeft > prevScrollLeft) {
      // if user is scrolling to the right
      return (thisCourusel.scrollLeft +=
        positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff);
    }
    // if user is scrolling to the left
    thisCourusel.scrollLeft -=
      positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff;
  };
}
```

```css
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  //display: flex;
  padding: 0 35px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #343f4f;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper i {
  top: 50%;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  color: #343f4f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}
.wrapper i:active {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
.wrapper i:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.wrapper i:first-child {
  left: -22px;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper i:last-child {
  right: -22px;
}
.wrapper .carousel {
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.carousel.dragging {
  cursor: grab;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}
.carousel.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel img {
  height: 340px;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.carousel img:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Draggable Image Slider | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <div class="carousel">
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
        </div>
        <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>hihifdd</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
      <div class="carousel">
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
      </div>
      <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It may behove you to use a `forEach()` loop to make the code more clear, like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".carousel").forEach((carousel) => {
  const firstImg = carousel.querySelectorAll("img")[0];
  const arrowIcons = carousel.closest(".wrapper").querySelectorAll("i");

  let isDragStart = false,
    isDragging = false,
    prevPageX,
    prevScrollLeft,
    positionDiff;

  const dragStart = (e) => {
    // updatating global variables value on mouse down event
    isDragStart = true;
    prevPageX = e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX;
    prevScrollLeft = carousel.scrollLeft;
  };

  const dragging = (e) => {
    // scrolling images/carousel to left according to mouse pointer
    if (!isDragStart) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    isDragging = true;
    carousel.classList.add("dragging");
    positionDiff = (e.pageX || e.touches[0].pageX) - prevPageX;
    carousel.scrollLeft = prevScrollLeft - positionDiff;
    showHideIcons();
  };

  const dragStop = () => {
    isDragStart = false;
    carousel.classList.remove("dragging");

    if (!isDragging) return;
    isDragging = false;
    autoSlide();
  };

  carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart);
  carousel.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart);

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
  carousel.addEventListener("touchmove", dragging);

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", dragStop);
  carousel.addEventListener("touchend", dragStop);

  const showHideIcons = () => {
    // showing and hiding prev/next icon according to carousel scroll left value
    let scrollWidth = carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth; // getting max scrollable width
    arrowIcons[0].style.display = carousel.scrollLeft == 0 ? "none" : "block";
    arrowIcons[1].style.display =
      carousel.scrollLeft == scrollWidth ? "none" : "block";
  };

  arrowIcons.forEach((icon) => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14; // getting first img width & adding 14 margin value
      // if clicked icon is left, reduce width value from the carousel scroll left else add to it
      carousel.scrollLeft += icon.id == "left" ? -firstImgWidth : firstImgWidth;
      setTimeout(() => showHideIcons(), 60); // calling showHideIcons after 60ms
    });
  });

  const autoSlide = () => {
    // if there is no image left to scroll then return from here
    if (
      carousel.scrollLeft - (carousel.scrollWidth - carousel.clientWidth) >
        -1 ||
      carousel.scrollLeft <= 0
    )
      return;

    positionDiff = Math.abs(positionDiff); // making positionDiff value to positive
    let firstImgWidth = firstImg.clientWidth + 14;
    // getting difference value that needs to add or reduce from carousel left to take middle img center
    let valDifference = firstImgWidth - positionDiff;

    if (carousel.scrollLeft > prevScrollLeft) {
      // if user is scrolling to the right
      return (carousel.scrollLeft +=
        positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff);
    }
    // if user is scrolling to the left
    carousel.scrollLeft -=
      positionDiff > firstImgWidth / 3 ? valDifference : -positionDiff;
  };
});
```

```css
/* Import Google font - Poppins */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}
body {
  //display: flex;
  padding: 0 35px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #343f4f;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper i {
  top: 50%;
  height: 44px;
  width: 44px;
  color: #343f4f;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 44px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: transform 0.1s linear;
}
.wrapper i:active {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.9);
}
.wrapper i:hover {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.wrapper i:first-child {
  left: -22px;
  display: none;
}
.wrapper i:last-child {
  right: -22px;
}
.wrapper .carousel {
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
.carousel.dragging {
  cursor: grab;
  scroll-behavior: auto;
}
.carousel.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.carousel img {
  height: 340px;
  object-fit: cover;
  user-select: none;
  margin-left: 14px;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
}
.carousel img:first-child {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: calc(100% / 2);
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
  .carousel img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Draggable Image Slider | CodingNepal</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
        <div class="carousel">
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
          <img
            src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg"
            alt="img"
            draggable="false"
          />
        </div>
        <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p>hihifdd</p>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <i id="left" class="fa-solid fa-angle-left"></i>
      <div class="carousel">
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back04.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back02.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back01.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
        <img
          src="https://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back07.jpg"
          alt="img"
          draggable="false"
        />
      </div>
      <i id="right" class="fa-solid fa-angle-right"></i>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The benefit here is that you don't get the dissonance between the naming of the `carousel` variable – where I expect it to be plural for a collection carousels.